# Assign ksh/bash array with awk

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, ksh

I'm trying to transform a given line to an array, for example this line :

> My first\t \tHello world

to the following ksh/bash array:

```
[0]="My first"
[1]=""
[2]="Hello world"
```

My code:

```
TAB=`printf '\011'`

query()
{
    echo "$1"|awk -F"$TAB" '
        { 
            for(i = 0; i < NF; i++)
                QueryArray[i]=$i
        }';
}

line=`head -n 1 myFile`
typeset -a QueryArray;
query "$line"
echo "Array length: ${#QueryArray[*]}"
echo "- " ${QueryArray[0]}
echo "- " ${QueryArray[1]}
echo "- " ${QueryArray[2]}
```

but doesn't work, any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an older ksh that does not understand `$'ANSI'` strings, so:

```
str2array () {
    typeset arrayname=$1
    typeset IFS=$2
    shift 2
    eval "set -A $arrayname \$*"
}

s="Hello        World"     # tabs entered literally with "Ctrl-V tab"
str2array myarray " " "$s"     # another literal tab as 2nd parm
typeset -i i=0
while [[ $i -lt ${#myarray[@]} ]]; do
    printf "%d\t%s\n" $i "${myarray[$i]}"
    i=$(( i+1 ))
done
```

---

for bash:

```
str2array () {
    local arrayname=$1
    local IFS=$2
    shift 2
    eval "$arrayname=( \$* )"
}

s=$'hello\t\tworld'
str2array myarray $'\t' "$s"
for (( i=0; i < ${#myarray[@]}; i++ )); do
    printf "%d\t%s\n" $i "${myarray[$i]}"
done
```

---

I'm getting the same result ar Arnaud's comment to David: with "word\t\tword", the middle field is being dropped. I don't see that with a different delimiter such as colon.

ksh

> Blank Interpretation
>       After parameter and command  substitution,  the  results  of
>       substitutions are scanned for the field separator characters
>       (those found in IFS) and split into distinct arguments where
>       such characters are found. Explicit null arguments ( "" ) or
>       ('') are retained.  **Implicit null arguments (those resulting
>       from parameters that have no values) are removed.**

bash

> Word Splitting
>          ...
>          The shell treats each character of IFS as a delimiter, and  splits  the
>          results of the other expansions into words on these characters.  If IFS
>          is unset, or its value is exactly `<space><tab><newline>`,  the  default,
>          then  sequences  of  `<space>`, `<tab>`, and `<newline>` at the beginning and
>          end of the results of the previous  expansions  are  ignored,  and  any
>          sequence  of  IFS  characters  not  at  the  beginning or end serves to
>          delimit words.  If IFS  has  a  value  other  than  the  default,  then
>          sequences of the whitespace characters space and tab are ignored at the
>          beginning and end of the word, as long as the whitespace  character  is
>          in  the  value  of IFS (an IFS whitespace character).  Any character in
>          IFS that is not IFS whitespace, along with any adjacent IFS  whitespace
>          characters,  delimits a field.  **A sequence of IFS whitespace characters
>          is also treated as a delimiter**.  If the value of IFS is null,  no  word
>          splitting occurs.

Comment: Seems to be I'm blocked, will accept your answer, thanks for reply !

Answer (score 1):

```
query()
{
    IFS=$'\t'
    ind=0       
    for i in $1 
        do 
          QueryArray[$ind]=$i 
          let "ind+=1" 
        done
    unset IFS

}

declare -A QueryArray;
query "Hello        World" #Hello\t \tWorld
echo "Array length: ${#QueryArray[*]}"
echo "- " ${QueryArray[0]}
echo "- " ${QueryArray[1]}
echo "- " ${QueryArray[2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Doesn't work in KSH.

You need to use `typeset` instead of `declare`, and use the `function` keyword. Otherwise, [satyajit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168762/satyajit)'s answer works just fine.

Kornshellified for you...

```
function query
{
    IFS=$'\t'
    ind=0
    for i in $1
    do
        QueryArray[$ind]=$i
        let "ind+=1"
    done
    unset IFS

}

typeset -a QueryArray #Actually this is optional in Kornshell
query "Hello                World" #Hello\t \tWorld

# What the heck? Might as well go all Korn: print vs. echo
print "Array length: ${#QueryArray[*]}"
print -- "- ${QueryArray[0]}"
print -- "- ${QueryArray[1]}"
print -- "- ${QueryArray[2]}"
```

Comment: It works only if you have a character between 2 `\t\t`, if you have `Hello\t\tWorld`, it will only return an array length of 2 and not 3 as I expect